# Import text file into python list has \n in each item. How to remove \n from each item during the import?

Tags: python, list

I am using the following code to extract text from .txt file into a list

```
with open("german.txt", "r") as f:
    stopwords = []
    for item in f:
      # print(item)
      stopwords.append(item)
    print(stopwords)
```

sample of the german.txt file

```
aber
alle
allem
allen
aller
alles
als
```

the results

```
['aber\n', 'alle\n', 'allem\n', 'allen\n'......
```

Why am I getting \n with each item? Is there an easy way to complete this without the \n

Comment: I know I can remove this by looping through each item but I am looking for an easy way to do this during the import.

Comment: This worked but am keen to see if there is an alternative way.. stopwords.append(item[0:-1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
stopwords.append(item.rstrip())
```

The [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) method:

> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped: